# removing multiple escape characters from javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this statement to invoke the javascript and removing the single quote escape character from the values that I am passing to javascript function.

```
<label style="text-decoration: underline" onclick="javascript:GetSelectedRow('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("systempath").ToString().Replace("'", @"\'"); %>','','',1);"><%#Eval("ID") %></label>
```

how can I modify the above line so that it also removes the double quotes and single quotes together.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.Replace("'", @"\'").Replace("\"", @"\\\"")`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to escape the string so it's safe to use in a javascript method call?
You could create a new property in your datasource that escapes the systempath property:

```
public string EscapedSystemPath
{
    get
    {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(systempath);
    }
}
```

and then you can data bind against it:

```
<label style="text-decoration: underline" onclick="javascript:GetSelectedRow('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("EscapedSystemPath") %>','','',1);"><%#Eval("ID") %></label>
```